# I ain't able to create Windows Service in WSO2

Tags: eclipse, wso2, windows-services, yajsw

I am really new in WSO2, and i having some little errors when trying to create a Windows Service in my console. Follow below:

```
C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\yajsw-stable-12.09\bat>call setenv.bat
"java" -Xmx30m -Djna_tmpdir="C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\yajsw-stable-12.09\bat\/../tmp" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar "C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\yajsw-stable-12.09\bat\/../wrapper.jar" -c "C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\yajsw-stable-12.09\bat\/../conf/wrapper.conf"
INFO: lib not found: C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\yajsw-stable-12.09\lib\extended\glazedlists\glazedlists-1.8.0_java15.jar
INFO: lib not found: C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\yajsw-stable-12.09\lib\extended\glazedlists\commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar
INFO: lib not found: C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\yajsw-stable-12.09\lib\extended\glazedlists\commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar
INFO: lib not found: C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\yajsw-stable-12.09\lib\extended\glazedlists\glazedlists-1.8.0_java15.jar
```

I am trying this tutorial: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service

And i am not able to receive the response to runConsole.bat. I already tried with CARBON_HOME created and without it. I create the wso2server before and tried without it. I am asking because i already searched for some hours for others with this problem but isn't found nothing that could solve my problem.

If anyone could help me i would stay quite grateful.
Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some compatibility issues with latest YAJSW versions. Please use 11.03 as per the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the response Bhathiya. I will try and as soon as i can i say if worked.

Comment: Bhathiya, i did what you said, but i had another problem, the service is started but stop soon. the message is that: 'exception java.io.ioexception: an existing connection was forcibly closed by remote'. If you need another message i can post all of that below.

Comment: Bhathiya, i found the resolution for my problems. First i changed the way for my CARBON_HOME variable, was setted to 'wso2_ei/wso2/broker', and i setted for 'wso2_ei/'. After i had a problem with the service start, i just changed the wrapper.tray variable, for true to false. And everything runs well. I will end the request. Thank you.